# Checking formatting of selected text in QTextEdit - PySide6

Tags: python-3.8, qtextedit, pyside6, pyqt6, qtextcursor

I' m working on a rich text editor and came across a small problem which I kind of solved with what seems like a "hack".

So I wanted to check if the selected text or the text in cursor position has any formatting, bold, italics etc and check the corresponding button that does the corresponding job but it gets weird.

if I do something like

```
                       if self.ed.fontItalic() is True:
                            self.italic.setChecked(True)
                        else:
                            self.italic.setChecked(False)
            
                        if self.ed.fontUnderline() is True:
                            self.uline.setChecked(True)
                        else:
                            self.uline.setChecked(False)
```

where "self.italic" and "self.uline" are checkable QPushButtons;

Only the format under the cursor gets checked, but not both buttons for italic and underlined, ie, if the selected text has bot formatting.

Basically, it ignores the selected text and looks for formatting of text under cursor.

So I I'm currently parsing the html to see if it has formatting;

```
   def check_formatting(self):

        if self.ed.textCursor().hasSelection():
            print(self.ed.textCursor().selection().toHtml())
            if "font-style:italic;" in self.ed.textCursor().selection().toHtml():
                self.italic.setChecked(True)
            else:
                self.italic.setChecked(False)

            if "text-decoration: underline;" in self.ed.textCursor().selection().toHtml():
                self.uline.setChecked(True)
            else:
                self.uline.setChecked(False)

        else:
            if self.ed.fontItalic() is True:
                self.italic.setChecked(True)
            else:
                self.italic.setChecked(False)

            if self.ed.fontUnderline() is True:
                self.uline.setChecked(True)
            else:
                self.uline.setChecked(False)
```

and code for formatting selected text or text under cursor on button click is as follows

```
    def set_italic(self):
                if self.italic.isChecked():
                    self.ed.setFontItalic(True)
                    if self.ed.textCursor().hasSelection():
                        if self.ed.fontItalic() != QTextFormat.FontItalic:
                            self.ed.setFontItalic(True)
                        else:
                            self.ed.setFontItalic(False)
                else:
                    self.ed.setFontItalic(False)
```

All of this works nearly as intended but it all feels super hacky. And with the html parsing, obviously, if the user enters "font-style:italic;" in the text edit and selects the entered text, button for italic gets checked.

I've been looking through a lot of stuff on the internet but none of them helps me achieve as much as the above code does.

[image]       [image]

Comment: This is the expected behavior: by default only the cursor position is used to check the format, which makes sense; if the selection contains multiple formats (or even multiple font weights, since there are other weights other than "normal" and "bold") what should the function return? You might be interested in the fact that the selection contains bold/italic/underlined text, but others might want to know if the selection *only* contains bold (or italic or underlined) text. Your approach is also faulty, as if you select text *inside* the format, you won't get any format information at all.

Comment: Let's suppose that you have a *big* selection with a *single* character with a different format, with your approach all the selection would result having that format, and that would be counterintuitive. In any case, if that's what you want, it can still be done, but you cannot use the html anyway, but you have to work with the QTextCursor and cycle through all formats in the selection (if any). Besides that, your logic for buttons is unnecessarily complex, since both the format function and the button toggle functions are booleans, just do `self.italic.setChecked(self.ed.fontItalic())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior is expected, from the programming point of view it's not possible to know if the developer is interested in knowing whether the selection has a format set at *any* point, or they want to know if it does *not* contain that format.

Also, checking the html of the document is conceptually wrong, as the format could be set outside the selection (including the usage of a default stylesheet), and it's also important to remember that the `toHtml()` function returns a "translation" of the underlying QTextDocument, it's not the document object itself.
The only proper way to verify the format at a specified position is by getting the [QTextCharFormat](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcharformat.html) of the text cursor for a given character position.

If you really want to check if the selection contains any format change at any position, no matter the cursor position, then you need to cycle through all characters in the selection and verify their format.

Note that in this case you need to connect to *both* `cursorPositionChanged` and `selectionChanged` signals, as the user could click on the editor at the cursor position, which would clear the selection but won't change the cursor position.

With the following code, the `check_formatting` function will automatically toggle buttons, so that you don't need to check the current format in the button function, but you can directly connect to the text edit functions as they will toggle the format exclusively based on the state set by `check_formatting`, thus overriding the default behavior.

```
class Editor(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.ed.cursorPositionChanged.connect(self.check_formatting)
        self.ed.selectionChanged.connect(self.check_formatting)

        self.bold.toggled.connect(self.toggle_bold)
        self.italic.toggled.connect(self.ed.setFontItalic)
        self.underline.toggled.connect(self.ed.setFontUnderline)

    def toggle_bold(self, bold):
        self.ed.setFontWeight(QtGui.QFont.Bold if bold else QtGui.QFont.Normal)

    def check_formatting(self):
        # assume no format by default
        bold = italic = underline = False
        cursor = self.ed.textCursor()
        if cursor.hasSelection():
            rangeEnd = cursor.selectionEnd() + 1
        else:
            rangeEnd = cursor.selectionStart() + 1
        for pos in range(cursor.selectionStart(), rangeEnd):
            cursor.setPosition(pos)
            fmt = cursor.charFormat()
            if fmt.fontWeight() >= QtGui.QFont.Bold:
                bold = True
            if fmt.fontItalic():
                italic = True
            if fmt.fontUnderline():
                underline = True
            if all((bold, italic, underline)):
                # all formats are set, no need for further checking
                break

        # set check states of buttons but block their signals to avoid
        # unnecessary calls and unwanted behavior when using keyboard
        # navigation for selection (eg: shift+arrows)
        with QtCore.QSignalBlocker(self.bold):
            self.bold.setChecked(bold)
        with QtCore.QSignalBlocker(self.italic):
            self.italic.setChecked(italic)
        with QtCore.QSignalBlocker(self.underline):
            self.underline.setChecked(underline)
```

Comment: I've already solved it with a similar method but with while loop. But your solution is much more robust. Thank you.